# RxJS get before/after emission values of Observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I'd like to calculate a difference between emissions of a single Observable.

Is there a way to get both the current and previous emission of an Observable if it emits a new value?
I'd like something like this:

```
ob$.subscribe(val => {
  console.log(val)
  // First emission: [1,2,3]

  // Second emission: [1,2,3,4]

  console.log(arrayDifference(before, after)) // [4]
})
```

How would I go about that? Do I need to store every emission in an upper-scope variable or is there a fancy RxJS way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the scan operator to check the previous value

```
   const arrayDifference = (before, after) => {
    // Immlement the fuction here
    
    const difference = .........
    return difference
    }
    
    
    ob$.pipe(scan((before,after) => arrayDifference(before,after), [])).subscribe(val =>  console.log(val))
```

This should work

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with [`bufferCount`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/bufferCount) operator which is very modular:

```
bufferCount(2, 1)
```

It'll create a new buffer of size `2` after every `1` emission from source.

Alternativelly, there also [`pairwise()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/pairwise) operator that does exactly the same thing .

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using the `scan` operator as it already gives me the before/after values without providing a buffer size and interval. Still a really valid answer if buffer sizes larger than 2 are required.

Answer (score 0):

I would use *startWith* and *pairwise()*

```
 const randomObservable = of('observableString')
  .pipe(startWith('defaultString'), pairwise())
  .subscribe(arrayOfStrings => console.log(arrayOfStrings[0], arrayOfStrings[1]));
```

The code above will console log: 'defaultString', 'observableString'.

Comment: I don't know the values that are being emitted in advance so I can't use `startWith()`.

Comment: 1 it's just to make the example leaner and shorter. 2 it's just to fill-in the buffer for the first iteration
3 startWith can be also set to null or Symbol if you don't have/know the values. 4 in TS you can always cast the observable to your desired type.
That being said, scan it's probably the best option for your OP. That's for sure.
Keep in mind that the bufferCount answer will start emitting only when the array buffer is completed, while my answer will emit as soon as randomObservable emits (since we start already with a value)